# Refactoring same loop logic with different input data

Tags: java

I have these two methods:

```
public static String buildLine(String[] values) {
    StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
        lineBuilder.append(values[i]).append(SEPARATOR);
    }
    lineBuilder.append(values[values.length - 1]);
    return lineBuilder.toString();
}

public static String buildLineFromNodeWorker(String[] values, NodeDecorator nodeWorker) {
    StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
        lineBuilder.append(
                nodeWorker.getItemValueFromAttribute(values[i]))
                .append(SEPARATOR);
    }
    lineBuilder
            .append(nodeWorker
                    .getItemValueFromAttribute(values[values.length - 1]));
    return lineBuilder.toString();
}
```

they're identical except for what I'm passing to the `append` method from the `StringBuilder`.

I'm not able to find a way to write the "business logic" of the loop just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
abstract class LineBuilder {
    protected abstract String getLine(String value);

    public String buildLine(String[] values) {
        StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
            lineBuilder.append(getLine(values[i])).append(SEPARATOR);
        }
        lineBuilder.append(getLine(values[values.length - 1]));
        return lineBuilder.toString();
    }
}

class StringLineBuilder extends LineBuilder {
    protected String getLine(String value) {
        return value;
    }
}

class NodeWorkerLineBuilder extends LineBuilder {
    private final NodeDecorator nodeWorker;

    public NodeWorkerLineBuilder(NodeDecorator nodeWorker) {
        this.nodeWorker = nodeWorker;
    }

    protected String getLine(String value) {
        return nodeWorker.getItemValueFromAttribute(value);
    }
}
```

Once you define the above classes you can replace the code inside your methods with:

```
public static String buildLine(String[] values) {
    return new StringLineBuilder().buildLine(values);
}

public static String buildLineFromNodeWorker(String[] values,
        NodeDecorator nodeWorker) {
    return new NodeWorkerLineBuilder(nodeWorker).buildLine(values);
}
```

Comment: Better explanation of the template method you can find here http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method

Answer (score 3):

A straight forward refactoring:

```
// Differing bit
private interface Function<X,Y> {
    Y apply(X x);
}

// Common bit
private static String buildLine(String[] values, Function<String, String> f) {
    StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {           
        lineBuilder.append(f.apply(s)).append(SEPARATOR);
    }
    lineBuilder.append(values[values.length - 1]);
    return lineBuilder.toString();
}

// call the common routine, supply differing part as a parameter
public static String buildLine(String[] values) {
    return buildLine(values, new Function<String, String>() {
        public String apply(String s) {
            return s;
        }
    });
}

// call the common routine, supply differing part as a parameter
public static String buildLineFromNodeWorker(String[] values, final NodeDecorator nodeWorker) {
    return buildLine(values, new Function<String, String>() {
        public String apply(String s) {
            return nodeWorker.getItemValueFromAttribute(s);
        }
    });
}
```

Two private methods above can be replaced with the following one if you have Guava libraries:

```
private static String buildLine(String[] values, Function<String, String> f) {
    return Joiner.on(SEPARATOR).join(
            Iterables.transform(Arrays.asList(values), f));
}
```

Comment: I cannot use the for loop because I would be writing the last element twice.

Comment: @dierre You're right. Removed that suggestion.